# Resend Docusign Envelope Through Apex Code

Tags: apex, code, docusign

I am new to Docusign . I have a usecase which we need to resend docusign envelope based on the recipients those who are not signed . Did any one have a sample code means please share here

Comment: Have you checked Docusign support resources?

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to do it via apex toolkit then you can do it like:
dfsle.StatusService.resendEnvelope(dfsle.UUID.parse(docusign envelope id));

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But when we use the above line means the owner of the envelope can able to resend the Envelope. We required either owner or the user can able to resend the envelope.

Comment: that's correct. I also need this solution so any docusign users can able to resend the Envelope. Please let me know if you found any solution.